# Load high quality image from Contacts

Tags: android, android-contacts

I found that my users got several images under the same contact id. I can access those images by running the next script:

```
private void loadImages(Context context, int contactId) {
    String[] selectionArgs = {String.valueOf(contactId)};
    String selection = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=? and " +
            ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.PHOTO + " is not null";
    String[] projection = {ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.PHOTO};
    Uri contentUri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
            contentUri,
            projection,
            selection, selectionArgs,
            null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        return;
    }
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        byte[] blob = cursor.getBlob(0);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(blob, 0, blob.length);
        saveToFile(context, bitmap);
        bitmap.recycle();
    }
}
```

But those just thumbnails. To get the full image file, I need to do some thing like that(Taken from [android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.html)):

```
public InputStream openDisplayPhoto(long contactId) {
     Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);
     Uri displayPhotoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, Contacts.Photo.DISPLAY_PHOTO);
     try {
         AssetFileDescriptor fd =
             getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(displayPhotoUri, "r");
         return fd.createInputStream();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         return null;
     }
 }
```

Any ideas how to get full size images by Contacts.DATA._ID?

Comment: what do you mean by `Contacts.DATA._ID`? you mean `ContactsContract.Data._ID`? as in an ID of a data row belonging to a contact?

Comment: @marmor yep this is it